# Barking up a tree ("barking up the wrong tree")

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, metaphors

I don't understand expression

> **barking up a wrong tree**

Does it think about putting bark on tree or taking it off?
A person says

> you're barking up the wrong tree

and he means

> don't bother me

But what is it from?
Does he mean the bark is wrong kind for the tree?
Like "I am oak, take your pine bark!"
In Croation we say **the wall is closed** meaning you have the wrong wall, have to climb through another with window.
Is that how this means?

Comment: This page should be useful: https://www.oxford-royale.co.uk/articles/bizarre-english-idioms-meaning-origins.html

Comment: @DamkerngT. thank you that is more red herring than I can all at once chew!

Comment: Since other answers seem to be missing this, I'd like to point out that in English, 'bark'  in this context refers to the sound a dog makes. Thus, when a dog is 'barking', they are making the noise with their mouths that sounds like the word 'bark'. Similar to 'yapping', 'growling', and 'whining', all of which refer to different dog noises.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh So is barking your shin because you are unhappy and whining about pain?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, I think that's the other barking, the one where you remove the bark (bark, here, referring to the skin of a tree). Wow, I did not ever think about this, but it gets complicated.

Comment: The whole mess around here is not constructive. Close vote...

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost can you help me understand why the sidebar is full of questions about idiomatic english usage that are on topic but this one is off topic? im sorry fi i caused any harm to the site.

Comment: -1, asker is [trolling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/troll#Verb). This is not a [practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a hunting dog that helps you catch a wild animal. If it climbs up a tree, the dog is supposed to bark at the tree it climbed up. Imagine the situation where the dog is barking at a different (wrong) tree and you would be very disappointed at the dog.

1. It could mean as a dog:

> You are wasting your efforts and energy by pursuing the wrong path. In
>   other words, you made the wrong choice.

2. As a tree:

> You are asking the wrong person. You have to ask somebody else. Leave me
>   alone. I am not the tree you want.

The verb [**bark**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bark) means the following:

> to make the characteristic short loud cry of a dog.

It has nothing to do with the noun *bark*:

> the tough exterior covering of a woody root or stem.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: So he says im disappointed hunting dog! Well i have a surprise for him next time we meet. We have another Croatian saying, "dont make an appointment", it mean you too busy looking for your teeth.

Comment: @EdPlunkett You don't have to take the meaning literally. It doesn't mean you are a hunting dog at all. It is just one of many metaphors or idioms in English.

Comment: Let him explain it is metaphor. maybe he can.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Without any context, it is difficult for anyone to know why he used the idiom.

Comment: No worry. i make him explain.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Notice that bark is the covering of a tree trunk and also what a dog does. The bark on the tree doesn't have anything to do with the expression though.

Comment: @shawnt00 yes I know, bark is skin on a tree and also skin of a dog. i understand metaphor.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's good! I was just going off what you wrote in the question.

Comment: The "bark" of trees and the "bark" of dogs are only the same word due to coincidence. They came from two completely different words long in the past that converged to the same word in terms spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost i thought meant you say dogs skin is "bark" like bark on tree. metaphor. both are covering animal.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost which bark is "Helen, thy beauty is to me. Like those Nicean barks of yore"? does mean shes wrong tree, is not beautiful?

Comment: @EdPlunkett The point of the metaphor is not to say that you are a dog, which I suppose could be taken as an insult. (To someone who doesn't know how much a good hunting dog costs ...) He is saying that you are looking in the wrong place. Which depending on context, might be an insult -- "You idiot! Don't you know where you should be looking?" -- or could simply be helpful advice -- "No, this isn't the right place. Try someplace elsse."

Comment: "Bark" is not the skin of a dog; it's the sound a dog makes.

Comment: @Jay Helens skin is not bark either so?

Comment: In the poem, "bark" refers to a type of ship, not the covering of a tree. http://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/history/bark-sailing-vessel.html He's comparing Helen's beauty to a ship made in Nicea, a Greek city in ancient Anatolia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaea I think he's trying to say that, like a ship brings a traveler home, so Helen's beauty causes a man to want to return to her. Why a "Nicean bark" and not any ship is not clear to me. The poem is full of allusions to Greek mythology, perhaps there's some specific myth about a Nicean bark returning home, I don't know.

Comment: @Jay if its mythology could helen by [tree goddess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caryatis)?

Comment: No, Helen was the queen of Troy, nothing to do with trees that I know of. She was renowned for her beauty, and her name is often used in poetry as a symbol of beauty. Dryads were demigoddesses of trees, and Daphne, Lotis, and Baucis were turned into trees. But none of these have anything to do with Helen.

Comment: @EdP - RE: _Well i have a surprise for him next time we meet_ Yikes! I hope you've changed your mind about that. The expression is completely neutral. It's a common idiom that carries zero insulting value. It's just an idiom, not unlike "raining cats and dogs" (which means "raining heavily") or "you're on a [wild goose chase](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wild+goose+chase)". As a helpful resource, I have found that [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bark+up+the+wrong+tree) explains idioms quite well.

Comment: I have a funny feeling this may be a troll account. "yes I know, bark is skin on a tree and also skin of a dog"

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 - I initially thought it was a genuine question. But based on the OP's posts elsewhere on the network, he seems to speak fluent English. Still, the answers on here are good, accurate, and helpful to anyone who ever does get confused by this idiom.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a dog who is **barking**:

[image]

<sup>["Drooker style dog"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drooker_style_dog.svg) by [Balthazar](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Balthazar), licensed [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)</sup>

Here is a dog who is **barking up a tree**:

[image]

<sup>["Treeing Fiest"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Unknown_dog_breed_treeing.jpg) by Scochran4, licensed [CC-BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/deed.en)</sup>

There is an animal in the tree that the dog wants to catch.

But what if the dog picked the wrong tree? (Maybe the animal jumped into a different tree and the dog didn't see. Maybe the dog didn't see which tree the animal climbed, and guessed wrong.) Then we could say that the dog is **barking up the wrong tree**.

When you ask someone for information, and they say, "You're barking up the wrong tree," it means, "I don't have the information you want."

This is metaphorically like the dog (you) trying to catch the animal (information) in the tree (person). The dog is barking up some tree, but the animal isn't in that tree. The animal is in a different tree. Similarly, you're looking for information from a person, but that person doesn't have the information. Someone else knows the information you want.

Answer (score 10):

Although the other skin of a tree is referred to as it **bark**, this is not what is meant by

> Barking up the wrong tree.

When a dog **gives chase** to a cat(as an example), it will **bark** while it frantically runs after the cat.
The cat may **run up a tree** to escape, leaving the barking dog below.
If the dog gets confused, (s)he may bark at/up a **tree with no cat**.

This is **barking up the wrong tree**

Looking for something in the **wrong place**

Answer (score 5):

This well-known phrase is an idiom, part of colloquial (AmE at least) speech, that means:

- you are investigating something/gathering information, and
- the action you're currently taking to find information will not help you, and
- you probably don't know this, so that's why someone is telling you this.

Contrived example:

> A: Hey Bob, I'm looking for Sally.  (A thinks Bob knows where Sally is)
>
> B: You're barking up the wrong tree, my friend.  She hasn't been around here for months.  (A obviously is not aware that Sally hasn't been around for months)

If you ask someone for information, and they respond with "you are barking up the wrong tree", they are indirectly telling you that they have not been involved whatsoever in what you are asking.  It's not quite equivalent to "don't bother me" - more like "don't bother me because I can't help you get what you want."

Another contrived example:

> Police officer: Sally said she talked to you at the restaurant, before she was murdered.  What did she say to you?
>
> Suspect: You're barking up the wrong tree.  I've never been at that restaurant.